# Curve integral, what am I doing?

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

Suppose $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$ and path defined $\alpha(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$, $0\leq t\leq 4\pi$

Going to find $\int_{\alpha}f ds$, but not completely sure in the final part.

Ok, first $x(t)=\cos t$ and $y(t)=\sin t$, so $dx/dt=-\sin t$ and $dy/dt=\cos t$

Thus $ds=\sqrt{\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t}dt=1dt$. So far so good.

Next $\int_{\alpha}fds=\int_0^{4\pi}\cos^2 t \sin^2 t dt$, and next step is what I am uncertain of - if I simply plug $t$ values in there, I get $0$.

$\alpha(t)$ goes in circle, and makes two full circle. If I plug anything ($\pi/x|x\in\mathbb{N}$), larger than $\pi/4$ I also get $0$.

for $t$ from $0$ to $\pi/4$ - $\int_{\alpha}=1/4$, and since we have $16$ such parts, full $\int=4$

Would someone be as kind, as to help me interpret - what I am to aim for in this case?

Comment: Plug $t$ in? You are supposed to calculate a primitive function and to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, I suppose?

Comment: @Aniket, no, it is a curve integral... Everything seems correct until OP has to calculate the integral $\int_0^{4\pi}\cos^2 t\sin^2t\,dt$, where he just wants to plug in some $t$ or something.

Comment: @mickep ok thanks for correcting. Your point is totally valid. That's why i upvoted it. He has to integrate it and then put the limits.

Comment: "Plug $t$", does sound indeed.. tacky. Question more regards - curve makes two full circle. How to understand it, from curve integral point of view - if to imagine $f$ geometrically, it makes "crownlike" figure - and i am not sure if this symmetric figure integral is 0, or sum of absolute values for its toothes.

Again tacky terminology, sorry for that.

Comment: The integrand is positive except at a finite number of points in the interval, so the integral can’t be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that I make mistage by "plugging" t into integrand, which actually doesnt make any sense.

With mistake corrected $\int_0^{4\pi} cos^2(t)*sin^2(t)dt=\rvert_0^{4\pi}1/8t - 1/32*sin(4t)=1/2\pi$, which now makes way more sense, because if we to integrate only one "full circle", result is $1/4\pi$